# Rounding numbers to 2 decimals only when necessary

Tags: javascript, arrays, tofixed

So I have the following code which extracts data from an array and calculates the average. The issue is that at the moment, even if the average is 3, it appears as 3.00. What I would like is for the average to only be to 2 decimal places if necessary. Code below:

```
var calculated = playerdata.map((player) => {
  const rounds = player.slice(2);

  return {
    player,
    average: average(rounds).toFixed(2),
    best: Math.min(...rounds),
    worst: Math.max(...rounds)
  };
}); 

function average(numbers) {
  return numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / numbers.length;
}
```

Comment: Not the question you're asking but you can drop the second argument ( `0` ) to reduce. By default on the first iteration, `a` will just be the first element of your `numbers` array, which for a sum doesn't change your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Maaz's solution also works, but here's a solution which is more self explanatory:

```
average(rounds) * 100 % 1 ? average(rounds).toFixed(2) : average(rounds)
```

This will round only if the number goes past 2 decimal places:

```js
f = function(a){return a * 100 % 1 ? a.toFixed(2) : a}

console.log(f(3))
console.log(f(3.1))
console.log(f(3.12))
console.log(f(3.128))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could prepend `average(rounds).toFixed(2)` with a `+`. Like

```
+average(rounds).toFixed(2)
```

Working examples:

```js
var roundTo2 = function(num) {
  return +num.toFixed(2);
}

console.log(roundTo2(3))
console.log(roundTo2(3.1))
console.log(roundTo2(3.12))
console.log(roundTo2(3.128))
```

UPDATE

Updating with relevant test cases

Comment: Will remove second decimal point if it is zero. Only works for your simple test case but not all cases

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string and prepending `+` (Unary operator - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) and [ECMAScript Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator)) to a string converts it to a number. The operation removes any trailing zeroes in the decimal representation as well.

Comment: @charlietfl What test case does this fail for?

Comment: With `+` returns 3.1 in both case.

Comment: Right and OP wants 2 decimal places if not integer

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated with the same test cases as the accepted answer. I see no difference in the output. Maybe your understanding of the OP's requirement is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Can compare rounded integer value of number to itself to see if it has decimal using [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```js
function printVal(num){ 
  var isDecimal = Math.round(num) !== num; 
  return isDecimal ? num.toFixed(2) : num;  
}

console.log(printVal(3.01));
console.log(printVal(3.1));
console.log(printVal(3));
```